# Can I use npm private github dependencies on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, ssh, npm, buildpack

I'm trying to push a Node.js application to Heroku. The app uses npm to fetch private github repositories, which are specified in `package.json`, like this...

```
"dependencies": {
    "my-private-dep": "github:my-org/my-repo"
}
```

The build fails during the `npm install` phase because the github host keys are not in the containers `known_hosts` file.

```
remote:        npm ERR! Host key verification failed.
```

This is expected behavior of SSH. Does Heroku provide a workaround for this? For example, [dokku](https://github.com/dokku/dokku), which uses the same [buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs) has a [host keys plugin](https://github.com/cedricziel/dokku-hostkeys-plugin) that will inject the host keys into the container before each build, which resolves this issue. Does Heroku have a similar solution?

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted out?  I'm fighting with the same problem in a Phoenix app...

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not. I bailed on Heroku and just paid $5/mo for a Digital Ocean server. Really surprised no one can answer this. It's pretty basic. I think maybe Heroku wants you to pay them for support or something

Comment: I actually did work out a solution - Heroku does not make this easy, but I found a buildpack that someone made that aaalmost worked for me - with a quick tweak, I was able to make it fly. I'll post my answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that there is a buildpack that makes this relatively easy -

https://github.com/debitoor/ssh-private-key-buildpack

However, I found that, for whatever reason, setting the `SSH_HOSTS` environment variable was not working correctly for me - according to the docs, it is supposed to set Github by default, and then you can add others if you like... I am actually using Gitlab for this particular project, but found that when I set the config like so:

```
$ heroku config:set SSH_HOSTS="git@gitlab.com"
```

it was not being detected.  I ended up forking the buildpack and changing `bin/compile` line 13 to

```
ssh_hosts=${SSH_HOSTS:-"git@gitlab.com"}
```

and just pushing it up to my own repo to use for this project.  Worked like a charm.

Comment: Do you know if this would still work if I needed to use the `node` buildpack? I am trying to deploy an API and ReactJS app together.

Comment: @tim.rohrer I would think so - but I believe that the SSH buildpack must come first in your buildpack order. In my case I'm running a Phoenix server, so my buildpack order is `ssh-key-private-buildpack` (my personal fork), `heroku-buildpack-elixir`, `heroku-buildpack-phoenix-static`, it all goes down smoothly.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to have to get smarter on buildpacks and building app.json files. Had hoped this would be easier :-)